# JDK not found on Debian 8.5

Tags: java, android, python-2.7, pygame

I want to make a python-android-app using [this software](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example). I have installed java JDK, when i run `java -version` i get:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

However running the line `python android.py installsdk` from witin rapt directory (as described in the tutorial) tells me that i have no JDK:

```
I'm compiling a short test program, to see if you have a working JDK
on your system.


I was unable to use javac to compile a test file. If you haven't
installed the Java Development Kit yet, please download it from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

The JDK is different from the JRE, so it's possible you have Java
without having the JDK. Without a working JDK, I can't continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your jdk to be accesible, and within path / java home :)

Here help from google:

> To set JAVA_HOME environment variable, do the following: Launch
>   Terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T on your keyboard. Depending on
>   where you installed your Java, you will need to provide the full path.
>   For this example, I installed Oracle JDK 7 in the
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle directory.Aug 13, 2012